# What language do Reaper JS plugins use?

Tags: reactjs, audio, programming-languages, reaper

I was wondering what I could do with the ReaJS plugins for my daw.
But there is no information about the language that they use.
I would say just by the name that is some Javascript Framework, but I am not very sure.
Can someone confirm this please?
If it is off-topic, where can i publish this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

ReaJS is a plugin that executes JSFX, a language to code real-time audio and MIDI plugins for REAPER. It has nothing to do with JavaScript.

The documentation can be found at https://www.reaper.fm/sdk/js/js.php.